# issue with condifr: puppet poiting to wong confdir

Tags: puppet

I am using puppet6 on centos 7.4. 
$ puppet config pring confdir 
is pointing to incorrect folder. I tried setting it to right folder but
set command does not have any effect. any clue what is happening?

Comment: We cannot say for sure without any details.  My first guess, however, is that you are running `puppet config print confdir` as yourself.  Puppet uses different configuration depending on who runs it.  Run it as root if you want properties used by the system service.

Comment: thanks for your pointer. I was using it non root user. all configurations are in ~/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/puppet.conf. After recreaton ~/.puppetlabs it is fine now. Thanks